# Can photon be treated like electron in terms of a matter-wave wavefunction $\psi$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, wavefunction

Photons can be described as electromagnetic waves in classical electrodynamics. Can photon be treated like electron in terms of a matter-wave wavefunction $\psi$ in quantum mechanics rather than quantum field theory? The photons here I mean both light in free space or surface plasmon polaritons in the surface of nanostructures.

Comment: SPP's are quite different from photons. I suggest to split the question in two.

Comment: You propose to treat a massless particle non-relativistically??